# Disable Application from sleeping in Windows 8 Metro

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am working on an app which displays videos and am running into an issue where the machine goes to sleep after hitting the sleep time limit while a video is playing.  Is there a way to disable this behavior in a Windows 8 Metro application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [DisplayRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br241816.aspx) class, specifically [DisplayRequest.RequestActive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.display.displayrequest.requestactive.aspx) for this purpose.  You must also remember to call DisplayRequest.RequestRelease once you are done to allow the display to sleep, for example, if you are not actively playing the movie, or in a menu screen, etc.

Comment: Thanks ZombieSheep!  That's it!

Comment: Not really related to the actual question, but i was wondering in which scenario you would call Activate more than once.

Comment: I'm not sure that you would, at least not deliberately.  It won't do you any good if you do.