# Waking the computer in Windows Store apps

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, microsoft-metro

How can we wake the computer from standby, sleep and/or hibernate in a Windows 8 metro-style application?

I have tried using the code I had for my old Winforms and WPF apps and even read and tried many tutorials online but nothing works. Also when searching for this there appears to be no results pointing to any kind of documentation.

Comment: Additional details: I have just discovered an app that prevents the Windows 8 device from going into Sleep mode.

Comment: Not possible, AFAIK. A central tenet of apps for the Windows Store is that the user is always in control. You can write apps that can run background tasks, but waking the device means consuming power, which the user might not want. As Hermit Dave notes, you can still write desktop apps if there's functionality you wish to provide that isn't supported in the Windows Store.

Comment: Preventing sleep is different from waking the machine. The ability to prevent a machine from going into sleep mode is provided for the purpose of media app scenarios, more specifically for apps that play video, since it would be pretty annoying to have the device sleep in the middle of a video.

Comment: @devhammer Desktop apps are not an option for me. How about Preventing the device from going into sleep mode? There is an app on the Windows store that does this. If that's there, then it must be allowed.

Comment: As noted above, those APIs are there for media playback apps. Using them for apps that don't play media (even assuming it's possible, as I haven't tried it) would likely result in unexpected behavior (from the end-user's standpoint) and could potentially keep your app from passing certification. Can you provide more detail on what you're trying to accomplish? Perhaps there's another approach that would work...

Comment: You haven't given the reason why you want the computer to wake at a specified time. Perhaps a timed notification is a good enough approximation.

Comment: There are plenty of alarm clock apps in the Store. However, I don't know if they keep the computer awake to be able to play the alarm.

Comment: @devhammer, the below-noted API's do not require your app to be a media app, that was just used as an example, and there are many other cases where these API's would be well-suited. Quoted from MSDN: "Apps that show video or run for extended periods without user input can request that the display remain on by calling DisplayRequest::RequestActive." Note how it says "... or run for an extended periods without user input can request that the display remain on...".

Comment: @jAsOn I would nonetheless argue, that being considerate of the user's resources obligates you to think long and hard about whether preventing the user's device from sleeping is the right approach. At a minimum, I'd suggest allowing the user to disable this behavior via the settings charm. Even better would be to make it opt-in, and give them feedback on first run that the feature exists, and the tradeoffs in turning it on.

Comment: @devhammer, you are correct in thinking this way, however the type of application I am releasing makes the user well aware of this feature and the user knows that in order for this app to be able to do its job, the computer must remain in a powered state where the app is able to function. If the user is not able, or not willing to keep their device on for an extended period of time while they're not using it, then this app isn't for them, since it's just not possible for this app to work without this feature. :-)

Comment: @jAsOn Fair enough...thank you for the clarification. And good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows RT does not expose such low level API if i am correct. Windows Store apps are for simple easy to use - mainly consumption apps.

You can however couple your windows store app with a ful windows app (desktop / traditional app) that your windows store app communicates with (WCF etc). The traditional app can do all it did before.

the only downside is that you cannot install your traditional app on Windows RT

Comment: If I remember correctly, the Windows Store guidelines prohibit your Metro-style apps from communicating with Desktop apps. I could be wrong though. But Releasing a Desktop app to the Store is not an option in my case, due to Microsoft's **stupid** account limitations. - But thank you for the suggestion. :)

Comment: I have just discovered some more details. There is an app on the Windows Store that prevents the device from falling asleep.

Comment: sure you can prevent app from sleeping.. i came across this post earlire today http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842599/disable-application-from-sleeping-in-windows-8-metro

Comment: BTW you can just have an app that can be installed from your hosting server.. not submitted to microsoft. something users browse and install themselves. Windows 8 does not have app source limitation (only there if you want it to be advertised on Store)

Comment: Thanks @Hermit, the DisplayRequest class is working very well. :)